# ffmpeg: stereo to 5.1 with all audio mapped to specific channel (either FL/FC/FR etc.)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, speakers

I have a stereo audio/video file from YouTube that contains a 20-20,000hz test tone sweep.  I want to make 6 different versions of this with the same video, but in each case all of the audio mapped to only one channel.  That is so that I can play the file on my HTPC and run the separate per-speaker EQ on my AVR and equalize the speakers independently, having the test tone only go to one speaker at a time, depending on which of the test files I select.

So for each of the 6 files, I want the audio mapped to one of these channels, and all of the other channels blank:

1. FL
2. FC
3. FR
4. SR
5. SL
6. LFE

Could someone please help me figure out the correct syntax to do that?

Comment: Hello, what did you try?

Comment: I didn't try anything.  I'm asking for help on what to do.

Comment: Questions like that aren't too welcome here and are way less likely to get an answer. Did you check ffmpeg documentation/guides for mapping?

Comment: See pan filter - https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan-1

Comment: I know there are a lot of ffmpeg questions, I also answered some of the ones that respected the rules of this website and showed any kind of effort. Also, the last sentence applies to you rather, as your answer will get deleted as it's link-only - you should really read about how this site works. https://superuser.com/help -> e.g. https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @BrianPeter This is not “arrogance” but open ended questions are not what this site is about. You have to show effort.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out myself using Audacity, FFMpeg and this simple guide...

https://www.frontiersoundfx.com/how-to-create-surround-sound-tracks-audacity/

Basically, for clarity:

1. Download and install Audacity
2. Launch Audacity and Under Preferences>Libraries, find the FFMpeg library and click Download.  Download and install it to it's default path.
3. Once the FFMpeg library is installed, go to Preferences>Import / Export.
4. Change selection box to “Use custom mix" (ie, to export a 5.1 multichannel file)
5. Drag and drop your stereo track into Audacity
6. From the "Tracks" menu select "Mix>Mix Stereo Down to Mono"
7. Add 5 more mono tracks (Tracks>Add New>Mono Track, 5x)
8. Now you have the 6 individual tracks you need to make a 5.1 multi-track audio file
9. Goto "File>Export>Export Audio" and from the "Save As Filetype" select "AC3 Files (FFMpeg)" and give it a name.
10. Then a graphical window will pop up showing your source tracks on the left and the output tracks on the right.  You can map your one actual track to whatever channel you want it to be in the 5.1 output file, where:

Channel 1=Left,
Channel 2=Center,
Channel 3=Right,
Channel 4=Left Surround,
Channel 5=Right Surround,
Channel 6=LFE

Obviously you can use this same process to create any 5.1 track (or 7.1, etc) you want using any number of input tracks you want rather than just the one actual track with the rest blanked as in my example.